# Denied Persons List

Tags: apex, security

Recently we were audited and our Legal findings found that we need to begin supporting the [US Govt DPL List](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/lists-of-parties-of-concern/denied-persons-list), and I was wondering if anyone here has had to deal with this list and if so what steps do I need to take?  Do we need to look into a web service, or is there another method?

Now I understand this could considered a general question, but I am concerned with it when it comes to Sales force

Comment: Great stuff in that DPL csv file - sure don't want to see my name there. Is it the CSV file that you want SFDC to be aware of?

Comment: Exactly.. I don't think I'm the first one to have this requirement and it is very interesting to see no discussions on it anywhere

Comment: did you look at a sample webservice like this one - http://mkdataservices.com/services/denied-party-screening.aspx ? I would do my damnedest to avoid recreating this functionality and let vendors do the work of staying up to date on the latest rules, regs, and parties of interest. just think of what is going on now between US - Russia over Ukraine

Comment: I was hoping that there was something on the AppExchange, but there isn't so now I will have to look into companies like mkdata.  This could be a good project for someone if they wanted to put something on the exchange, I feel like this could be a big deal for some companies